# What's the best way display tabs/spaces in my plain text files

Tags: editors, text, text-formatting

I have a file that unfortunately contains both tabs and spaces.

How do I display them so I know if a particular space is actually tab or space?

Answer (score 2):

Several options:

POSIX:

```
$ printf 'a b\tc \n' | sed -n l
a b\tc $

$ printf 'a b\tc \n' | od -A n -t cx1
   a       b  \t   c      \n
  61  20  62  09  63  20  0a
```

fairly portable:

```
$ printf 'a b\tc \n' | cat -vte
a b^Ic $
```

(some `cat` implementations have `-A` as an alias for `-vte`). Use only `-vt` or `-T` with GNU `cat`  if you only care about tab characters and not trailing spaces. Note that the list of characters that `cat` transforms varies with implementations.

In `vi` or `view`, enter `:set list` for the tabs and end of lines to become visible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your editor is a fairly modern version of Emacs, then `whitespace-mode` is what you're looking for.  You can customise which questionable whitespace to highlight via the variable `whitespace-style`:

> `whitespace-style` is a variable defined in `whitespace.el`.   Its value
>   is
>   `(face tabs spaces trailing lines space-before-tab newline indentation empty space-after-tab space-mark tab-mark newline-mark)`
>
> Documentation: Specify which kind of blank is visualized.
>
> It's a list containing some or all of the following values:
>
> - **`face`**            enable all visualization via faces (see below).
> - **`trailing`**        trailing blanks are visualized via faces.
>           It has effect only if `face` (see above)            is present in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`tabs`**            TABs are visualized via faces.
>     It has effect only if
>     `face` (see above)            is present in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`spaces`**      SPACEs and HARD SPACEs are visualized via           faces.
>           It
>     has effect only if `face` (see above)             is present in
>     `whitespace-style`.
> - **`lines`**       lines which have columns beyond             `whitespace-line-column`
>     are highlighted via           faces.
>               Whole line is highlighted.
>       It
>     has precedence over `lines-tail` (see             below).
>     It has effect
>     only if `face` (see above)            is present in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`lines-tail`**      lines which have columns beyond
>           `whitespace-line-column` are highlighted via            faces.
>     But
>     only the part of line which goes          beyond `whitespace-line-column`
>     column.
>     It has effect only if `lines` (see above)             is not
>     present in `whitespace-style`             and if `face` (see above) is present
>     in            `whitespace-style`.
> - **`newline`**     NEWLINEs are visualized via faces.
>       It has effect only
>     if `face` (see above)             is present in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`empty`**       empty lines at beginning and/or end of buffer           are
>     visualized via faces.
>     It has effect only if `face` (see above)
>           is present in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`indentation::tab`**    8 or more SPACEs at beginning of line are
>           visualized via faces.
>     It has effect only if `face` (see above)
>           is present in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`indentation::space`**  TABs at beginning of line are visualized via
>           faces.
>     It has effect only if `face` (see above)          is present
>     in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`indentation`**     8 or more SPACEs at beginning of line are
>           visualized, if `indent-tabs-mode` (which see)           is non-nil;
>     otherwise, TABs at beginning of           line are visualized via faces.
>           It has effect only if `face` (see above)            is present in
>     `whitespace-style`.
> - **`space-after-tab::tab`**        8 or more SPACEs after a TAB are
>               visualized via faces.
>               It has effect only if `face` (see above)
>               is present in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`space-after-tab::space`**  TABs are visualized when 8 or more
>               SPACEs occur after a TAB, via faces.
>               It has effect only if `face` (see above)
>               is present in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`space-after-tab`**     8 or more SPACEs after a TAB are
>               visualized, if `indent-tabs-mode`
>               (which see) is non-nil; otherwise,
>               the TABs are visualized via faces.
>               It has effect only if `face` (see above)
>               is present in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`space-before-tab::tab`**   SPACEs before TAB are visualized via
>               faces.
>               It has effect only if `face` (see above)
>               is present in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`space-before-tab::space`** TABs are visualized when SPACEs occur
>               before TAB, via faces.
>               It has effect only if `face` (see above)
>               is present in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`space-before-tab`**        SPACEs before TAB are visualized, if
>               `indent-tabs-mode` (which see) is
>               non-nil; otherwise, the TABs are
>               visualized via faces.
>               It has effect only if `face` (see above)
>               is present in `whitespace-style`.
> - **`space-mark`**      SPACEs and HARD SPACEs are visualized via           display
>     table.
> - **`tab-mark`**        TABs are visualized via display table.
> - **`newline-mark`**        NEWLINEs are visualized via display table.